# Jquery - How to append div with numeric id generate by PHP to div with element link with same numeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem to append my elements with different numeric id to closest div to element (link) with same numeric value as href ? Thank you very much.

JSFiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4FRg5/)

My Jquery Try without success because I am stuck:

```
$('.pagination').each(function(){
        var num_id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
        if($('.ui-body h2 a').attr('href').indexOf(num_id) != -1){
            $('.ui-body h2 a').closest('<div>').append($(this));
        }    
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pagination65" class="pagination"></div> <!-- genereate by php function -->
<div id="pagination26" class="pagination"></div> <!-- same with different number at end -->

<div class="col-bottom-2">
  <div class="ui-body" style="background-color: #FCFCFC;"> <!-- This is div here I need append those div with same ID as href number in link below -->
    <h2 class="main" style="color: #236EE8;">
    <a class="ui-link" href="/cz/cs/65_chystane-akce.html" style="color: #236EE8;"> Chystané akce </a>
    <a class="small ui-link" href="/cz/cs/65_chystane-akce.html" style="color: #236EE8; float:right;"> >> </a>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-body" style="background-color: #F6F6FD;"></div>
  <div class="ui-body" style="background-color: #FCFCFC;"></div>
  <div class="ui-body" style="background-color: #F6F6FD;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you appending another pagination class element? What do you expect $(this) to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 1 error and one incomplete code line.

You error is on line 4 of your JS. You are missing the simple or double quotes on the selector:

```
$('.ui-body h2 a').closest('<div>').append($(this));
```

You incomplete code comes from the `match()` part. `match()` returns an array of what it matches. Since you only have one match (both by not defining the `g` flag and by only having one instance of digits), you need to do `num_id[0]` on this line:

```
if($('.ui-body h2 a').attr('href').indexOf(num_id[0]) != -1){
```

Hope that helps.

You could also simplify the process by doing:

```
$('.ui-body h2 a[href*=' + num_id[0] + ']').append($(this));
```

The way you are doing it is flawed because when you have multiple results from a selector and you try to get an attribute from that selection jQuery will focus on whatever it finds first and forget about the rest.

Complete JS code:

```
$('.pagination').each(function () {
    var num_id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
    $('.ui-body h2 a[href*=' + num_id[0] + ']').append($(this));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for post. I create fiddle as you can see it still doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/Pd5q2/

Comment: Man I am so close now Where is problem in my code `$('.ui-body h2 a href*=' + num_id + ']').parent($('[class^=col-bottom]')).append($(this));`

Answer (score 1):

There were two small issues with your code.
1. Your num_id returned an object so i parsed it into an`int`
2.  you were missing the single quotes on your query selector inside your if statement

```
$('.pagination').each(function(){
  var num_id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
  num_id = parseInt(num_id[0],10);
  if($('.ui-body h2 a').attr('href').indexOf(num_id) != -1){
    $('.ui-body h2 a').closest('div').append($(this));
  }    
});
```

saw this before you added the fiddle, here's my jsbin
http://jsbin.com/cajux/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you for time and effort.

Comment: Can you please help me with last thing how to append this element just before close tag of parent element div. I've tried this syntax and It appends: `$('.ui-body h2 a[href*=' + num_id + ']').parent($('[class^=col-bottom-]')).append($(this));` It append after close <a element not before close parent div element ?

Comment: The first thing i notice is that you are only calling `.parent()` which goes up one level. You will want to call `.parents()` to traverse up till it finds the match. [jQuery Parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) I'm quite confused on what you are passing in `$('[class^=col-bottom-]')`  If you don't need to find the specific parent you can simplify it to `$('.ui-body h2 a[href*=' + num_id + ']').parent().parent().append($(this));` which will just go up two levels, first to the `h2` then to the `div`, and then append.

Comment: You're Welcome, If ya ever have any questions you can always tweet me `@Freytag`